# odbc_prepare, no se ejecuta ¿por que?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

estoy haciendo una ejecucion desde php asi:

```
    $query1 = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT User FROM sqlsv2008r2.dbo.tabla WHERE email = ? ");
    $result_1 = odbc_execute($query1, array($email));
    if(odbc_num_rows($result_1)>0)
    {
        die("<center><h2><font color='red'>El Correo</font> <font color=#EEEA0B'>$email</font><font color='red'> NO esta Disponible</font></h2></center>");
    }
```

Me sale este error:

```
Warning: odbc_execute() [function.odbc-execute]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecute in C:\xampp\htdocs\gg\ar_.php on line 3
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo? Uso SQL server 2008 r2

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la columna `email` en la base de datos?

Comment: varchar porque existe alguna para email expecifica? es SQL server 2008 r2 lo que uso

Comment: El error se debe a una limitación del controlador que estás usando, para más detalles revisa [este post de knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/3291) y tambien [este post](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P176851). Revisa sobre todo lo que se dice en el apartado **Resolution** del primer enlace. Considera declarar tu columna `email` de un tipo más pequeño, `varchar(max)` es exagerado para un email, pues tiene un tamaño de 8,000 caracteres. El estándar suele ser `varchar(320)` según [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37021).

Comment: Amigo hay no se entiende nada por que no publica una respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a una limitación (totalmente justificada) del controlador que estás usando, para más detalles revisa [este post de knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/3291) y tambien [este post](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P176851).

En el apartado **Resolution** del primer enlace dice lo suguiente:

> Este es el comportamiento esperado. No es posible usar un parámetro
> del tipo varchar (max) en una cláusula WHERE cuando se usa un operador
> igual.
>
> Utilice la función [SQLGetTypeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714632(VS.85).aspx) para averiguar qué tipos de
> datos se pueden buscar. El nombre de la columna `SEARCHABLE` devuelve
> `SQL_PRED_CHAR` para el tipo de datos `varchar (max)`: se devuelve
> `SQL_PRED_CHAR` si la columna se puede utilizar en una cláusula
> `WHERE`, pero solo con el predicado `LIKE`. (Este es el mismo que el
> valor `SQL_LIKE_ONLY` en ODBC 2.x.)

Es decir, ODBC limita que se puedan usar columnas demasiado grandes en criterios del tipo `WHERE laColumna = elValor` por motivos de rendimiento (generalmente uno no declara una columna enorme para usarla filtrando u ordenando datos).

Tu columna `email` al ser declarada de tipo `varchar(max)` va a tener un tamaño de 8,000 caracteres. ¿Acaso habrá una dirección de correo electrónico con 8,000 caracteres?

### Solución

Declara tu columna `email` con un tamaño más pequeño. Según  [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37021) el tamaño estándar para columnas con direcciones de correo electŕónico suele ser `varchar(320)`.

Otra solución (mediocre para este caso) sería cambiar el `WHERE` por un `LIKE`.

Otra solución (mediocre también para este caso), es la que se indica en el segundo de más arriba, que consiste en pasar a la versión 10 de ODBC.

Las dos son mediocres porque aunque funcione, lo más grave aquí es un error de diseño al destinar 8,000 caracteres a una columna cuyos datos jamás de los jamases llegarán a esa longitud.

Comment: Ammmm y como seria el codigo en la web? por que la verdad no se le entiende nada de nada

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez no hay ningún código en la web, lo que tienes que hacer es **definir la columna `email` en la base de datos de tipo `varchar(320)`** (supongo que sabrás cómo hacer eso). OJO, si es una base de datos en producción (con muchos datos y ya en uso) haz una copia de seguridad de la misma antes de cambiar el campo, por si acaso, si es una base de datos nueva simplemente haz el cambio. Cuando declares una columna más pequeña no tendrás el error.